# Is there an adjective for people who asks for more than offered?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

In Chile, we say someone is "patudo" when they ask for more than what was offered, like someone who stays for lunch the next day from a party, when offered only to stay the night. Could I rephrase the following sentence with something like "patudo"?

> I know someone that has helped me a lot some time ago, and I could
>   ask them for another favor, but I don't want to because I don't want to
>   be too 'patudo.'

Is there a word in English for "patudo"?

Comment: I think we just say 'greedy' in English.'I don't wish to sound greedy, but may I . . . . . . .'

Comment: Maybe we need to bring your Chilean word, 'patudo' into English. I quite like the sound and the meaning of it myself. I am using it already.

Comment: [presumptuous](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+presumptuous&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&oq=define+presumptuous&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.8868j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @NigelJ Cool, but use it with care, I am Chilean and I know the meaning of the word in Chile, but maybe it might mean something else for people of other Spanish-speaking countries.

Comment: @user4052054 Good point, considering how famous Spanish slang is for being subject to regional variation. The [Diccionario de la lengua española](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SC8ktVo) shows that this particular meaning is peculiar to Chile, and that it has another meaning in other regions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This idiomatic expression uses a verb phrase instead of an adjective:

> I could ask them for another favor, but I don't want to **take advantage of them**.

or even (in spoken language):

> I could ask them for another favor, but I don't want to **take advantage**.

**[Take advantage:](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=advantage)**

> To make use of for selfish reasons; achieve a selfish goal by
>   exploiting: *took advantage of him by leaving him with the bill; took
>   advantage of his unsuspecting nature*.

Comment: +1. Equivalently: "I don't want to impose (on them)".

Comment: @ruakh I'd suggest posting that as an answer.

Comment: @ruakh, I agree with Muzer

Answer (score 3):

"I know someone who has helped me a lot some time ago, and I could ask them for other favor, but I don't want to because I don't want to *overstep*."

For the more specific example of staying for lunch, an applicable term would be "outstay my welcome."

Comment: Thanks. I thought the same concept, but it's too specific to the lunch situation, and most important, it describes the action, but does not describe the person doing it. I want something like "welcome overstayer", an adjective. I'm going to edit the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I looked up the Chilean definition, which roughly translates to "Bold or Confident".  Other translations colloquially suggest someone with big feet or big eyes, combined this all seems to suggest a specific personality trait being used as an adjective in this negative connotation.

I feel the best adjective match would be the word "imposing", using your usage examples, the sentence structure still fits and conveys the meaning you appear to want.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "I could ask them for another favour but I don't want to **push my luck**"

[push_ones_luck](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/push-your-luck)

Comment: Although they might well describe the same behavior, I think the meaning of that one is quite different: "push one's luck" is mostly practical, focusing on the uncertainty of the outcome (and sometimes implying that the request might actually backfire -- if you ask for too much, you might piss them off and end up with nothing), whereas the OP's description of "patudo" indicates that it's judgmental, focusing on the rudeness of the behavior rather than its consequences.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is "exigent".

> **[Exigent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exigent)**:
>
> requiring or calling for much; demanding; as in >> an exigent client

Comment: It appears that 'exigent' is a matter of demanding urgency of action rather than a repeated action. The OP specifies, 'asking for more than is offered.'